# Weird memory error in wordpress wp-db.php

Tags: php, wordpress, memory

I get a weird error, as it only happens when trying to edit a page. On Posts it is working fine. As both using the same DB-Tables and scripts, that's really confusing. It happens after I transferred my Website to another Host with more power.

I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57344 bytes) in /www/htdocs/w01a0cda/wom87.de/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2033**

Line 2033:
`$this->result = mysqli_query( $this->dbh, $query );`

Already done:

- Increase memory size. every time its full and looking for additional 57344 bytes.
- Check Database -> nothing special. Not too big, not working much, no errors
- Check Logs -> Nothing to see here
- Asked Host-Partner -> Also the experts can't locate the error after checking for hours.
- Plugins are deactivated
- Original WordPress-Theme active
- Debug mode and error reporting is on.
- Console is empty

Notes: On the Page where the editor should be, is no working ajax/JavaScript. On click on js-buttons nothing happens. Even in console is nothing shown.

Location: The Error comes inside of the Page-Attributes Box. Not on top of the Page.

I hope somebody can help. It seems like something is stuck, pushing everything into memory until its full and pushes this error. (it was starting at 256MB -> 512MB -> 768MB | every time the same. Memory full -> wants 57344 more bytes)

Google didn't helped me out and in sof-search I found nothing similar.

Comment: yes, chmods are ok, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in file meta-boxes.php add a hashtag in front of the add_meta_box function in line 1502.

```
if ( post_type_supports( $post_type, 'page-attributes' ) || count( get_page_templates( $post ) ) > 0 ) {
    #add_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', $post_type_object->labels->attributes, 'page_attributes_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core', array( '__back_compat_meta_box' => true ) );
}
```

I finally found a solution. Not a good one, but it's working.
After lots of searches and attempts to solve this error, i was thinking about what can be able to load such a big amount of data in an attributes-box? So the solution was -> Parent page.
As Wordpress allways shows a meta-box with a dropdown where you can choose another page as parent page, this box loads all of my pages at once (18.000+). That was causing a massive amount of memory in Database and Webspace.
So i try to find a way to just delete that meta-box, but it seems not so easy, as the function remove_meta_box only works after the meta_box is added. So you need to prevent that meta-box from getting included.